# jquery find element with class and style display:block

Tags: jquery, css, highlight

I am retrieving the number of "found" elements (these elements have the `.highlight` class) with this simple jQuery snippet:

```
$(".highlight").length
```

But now my problem is that some elements are hidden, via `style="display: none;"`

Now, How can I get the number of elements highlighted AND displayed?

Something like:

```
$(hasClass 'highlight' AND has style 'display: block'). length ?
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use **[:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)** to get element which are visible.

```
$(".highlight:visible").length
```

Answer (score 8):

One way is to use `:visible` jQuery pseudo selector as Adil mentioned.

A common pitfall is that if the element with class `.highlight` is nested to a container which is hidden then you wont be able to get it even though that element has `display: block`

Instead you could use css regex as follows:
`$('.highlight[style*="display: block"]')`

A common pitfall is that you need to know exactly how the rule is written. If there is no space before `block` like so: `display:block` instead of `display: block` you wont be able to get the element either.

A way to overcome this is to search only for the term `block` in the styles like so:
`$('.highlight[style*="block"]')`

Answer (score 5):

U can also do by using [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)   to see the element  has css  `display="none"` or `display="block"`

```
 $(".highlight").each(function(){
       if($(this).css("display")=="block"){
          //Your code here
       }
    });
```

Comment: Its great solution I've looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pure JS version:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.one')).filter(s =>
   window.getComputedStyle(s).getPropertyValue('display') != 'none'
);
```

Returns all elements with class name `.one` and attribute `display: block`.